# Collapsing a div element that contains a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a user sign up form that i am trying to collapse once the user has successfully signed up (and replaced with something like 'please check your email to activate account') . I am having problems collapsing the form (and all the elements inside it) after receiving the correct response from an ajax request. I just cannot figure out where my code is incorrect. Please can someone advise?

Ajax request:

```
 // Create XMLHttprequest
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            //Need to get a response after processing the submitted data.
            if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'Sign up success'){
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                document.getElementById('signup_main').style.display='none';

            }else{
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try moving the line _document.getElementById('signup_main').style.display='none';_ outside the Ajax call - that way you can figure out, if the problem is with hiding the form or with your Ajax call.

Comment: probably not solving your question here, but make sure you know what type of data you're working with and replace all `==` with `===` as a first step ;)

Comment: Have you checked your id correctly? Does this document.getElementById('signup_main') return the element you want? Otherwise, I don't see any issue with the display none

Comment: Also check if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'Sign up success') is true

Answer (score 0):

```js
function adduser()
{
    $("#inp").hide(0);
    $("#main").html("User added successfully");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="inp">
    <p> A Div with content or form</p>
    <input type="button" value='add' onclick='adduser();'>
  </div>
</div>
```